# How can I fix a website which dosen't work with ubuntu?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

I want to make a website in a local environment, but I have a issue. I don't know why, but when I launch the website, I have the php code of the index.php file instead of having a view.

Here is what I did about the configuration:

I created a VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName dev.mywebsite.com
        ServerAlias www.dev.mywebsite.com
        DocumentRoot "/mnt/d/Websites/mywebsite"
        <Directory "/mnt/d/Websites/mywebsite">
                Options +FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride all
                Require all granted
                Options Indexes
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.dev.mywebsite.com.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.dev.mywebsite.com.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I modified the 'hosts' file with this two lines:

```
127.0.0.1       dev.mywebsite.com
::1             dev.mywebsite.com
```

Then I reloaded the service apache2.

But I still have a problem. Indeed, when I go to 'dev.mywebsite.com', I have a page with the code of the index.php, and I don't know why. I thought it was because php, but I have the version php 7.4.3.

Can you help me?

Thanks by advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the PHP Apache mod installed and enabled by:

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php
sudo a2enmod php7.4
```

Otherwise your web server knows nothing about php files and just shows them to the client.